# How to improve summary SQL on table with multiple joins and subqueries?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g, left-join

I have a query that summarizes results for the past day, past 7 days, past 30 days and all time per ID. The query I have works - but it is slower than I was expecting.

This is the query I am running

```
SELECT 
  v.id,
  v.dtt,
  v.date_hours as day_date_hours,
  w.date_hours as week_date_hours,
  m.date_hours as month_date_hours,
  t.date_hours as total_date_hours

FROM example v
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, sum(date_hours) as date_hours from example WHERE dtt > sysdate-7 group by id) w
  ON w.id = v.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, sum(date_hours) as date_hours from example WHERE dtt > sysdate-30 group by id) m
  ON m.id = v.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, sum(date_hours) as date_hours from example group by id) t
  ON t.id = v.id
WHERE
  dtt = '20-AUG-2014'
GROUP BY v.id, v.dtt, v.date_hours,  w.date_hours, m.date_hours, t.date_hours
order by v.id
```

This is a summary of the output

```
+-----+--------------------------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| ID  |              DTT               | DAY_DATE_HOURS  | WEEK_DATE_HOURS  | MONTH_DATE_HOURS  | TOTAL_DATE_HOURS |
+-----+--------------------------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|  1  | August, 20 2014 00:00:00+0000  | 18.5            | 111.65           | 415.25            | 444.75           |
|  2  | August, 20 2014 00:00:00+0000  | 10.5            | 116.65           | 451.55            | 475.05           |
+-----+--------------------------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

A few notes, unlike this sample for the question, the table `example` is actually a view. I do not control the view. It is a view I have been provided, but it looks exactly like the `example` table. It has this defination:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
        id varchar(15),
        dtt DATE,
        date_hours NUMBER
);
```

The view contains about 200K records across approximately 1000 unique IDs. My query takes about 8 minutes to run.

I suspect that my issue is that I am doing 3 subqueries on my JOINs. Despite this hunch, I'm not sure how (or if) there is a more efficient way to gather these summarize statistics. At an 8 minute run time, I could select the entire table and do all the calculations in my application faster. I'd rather not do this.

A link to a sample set of my table and query is available on this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a01b8/4/0)

How can I make my query more efficient, yet maintain the same resultset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the summary once, using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT v.id, v.dtt, v.date_hours as day_date_hours,
       h.week_date_hours, h.month_date_hours, h.total_date_hours
FROM example v LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT id,
             sum(case when dtt > sysdate-7 then date_hours end) as week_date_hours,
             sum(case when dtt > sysdate-30 then date_hours end) as month_date_hours,
             sum(date_hours) as total_date_hours
      from example
      group by id
     ) h
     ON h.id = v.id
WHERE dtt = DATE '2014-08-20'
order by v.id ;
```

I don't think the outer `group by` is necessary.  If so, you can just use `select distinct`.

EDIT:

I also think you can write this just using analytic functions:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM (SELECT v.id, v.dtt, v.date_hours as day_date_hours,
             sum(case when dtt > sysdate-7 then date_hours end) over (partition by v.id) as week_date_hours,
             sum(case when dtt > sysdate-30 then date_hours end) over (partition by v.id) as month_date_hours,
             sum(date_hours) over (partition by v.id) as total_date_hours
      FROM example v 
     ) v
WHERE dtt = DATE '2014-08-20'
order by v.id ;
```

Comment: Both of these worked, however the analytic functions one is much faster. Thank you.

Comment: @Andy . . . How much faster?

Comment: Your first query took 6 minutes, the analytic one took 30 seconds.